# list comprehension fails but why?

Tags: python

Who can explain to me why this list comprehension fails:

```
provider1 = {'id': 1, 'name': 'Een'}
provider2 = {'id': 2, 'name': 'Twee'}
provider3 = {'id': 3, 'name': 'Drie'}
provider4 = {'id': 4, 'name': 'Vier'}
provider5 = {'id': 5, 'name': 'Vijf'}
provider6 = {'id': 6, 'name': 'Zes'}
provider7 = {'id': 7, 'name': 'Zeven'}

providers = [provider1, provider2, provider3, provider4, provider5, provider6, provider7]


def testfunc(id):
    return next(provider for provider in providers if int(provider['id']) == int(id))


for x in range(0, 8):
    print testfunc(x)
```

When I run this and 0 is passed to the funtion, the output from this is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/scratchpad/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    print testfunc(x)
  File "/Users/me/Documents/scratchpad/main.py", line 13, in testfunc
    return next(provider for provider in providers if int(provider['id']) == int(id))
StopIteration

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It does work for a non zero integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `next` function raises `StopIteration` when there's no next item. In particular this occures when the underlying iterator is empty which is your case for `id == 0`.

Comment: Ok, that is logical of course. So, that means this way of doing it is dangerous in this case and a for loop iterating providers would be a better choice in this case. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Not really dangerous. You can simply wrap the `next` call with `try: ... except StopIteration: ...` block. All you have to do is figure out what you want when there is no item by the given criterium.

Comment: True, I wanted to do this because it is written elsewhere that this way is a lot faster. But if you `try` and catch `StopIteration` I wonder if you still would gain anything, and would I not make it more complex to read than a `for` over `providers` with an `if int(provider['id']) == int(id)` and `return provider`... I'll check that.

Comment: Turns out, again logic, that if you are expecting a lot of exceptions to be thrown, you're better off with the for loop. If you have a big list and seldom an exception, you're WAY better of with a comprehension construction!

Comment: If you can guarantee that `id` is unique on each object then there's an easier solution. Simply convert the list into a dictionary `{id: object}`. Then searching is `O(1)`, compared to `O(n)` for lists. That's basically how indexes work.

Answer (score 2):

The  dictionary does not have a value for key `0`. It finds value as `None` and it cannot determine the next value for iteration.
Replace your code with valid ranges, your code will work

```
for x in range(1, 8):
    print( testfunc(x))
```

**OR**

You could add `provider0 = {'id': 0, 'name': 'Onkar'}`

and `providers = [provider0,provider1, provider2, provider3, provider4, provider5, provider6, provider7]` to make

```
for x in range(0, 8):
    print( testfunc(x))
```

work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because your generator is empty. None of your data matches

```
if int(provider['id']) == 0
```

Calling `next` on an empty generator throws the `StopIteration`.